# Computing running sum with moving time-window

Tags: stata, duration, survival-analysis

**My data**

I am working on a spell dataset in the following format:

```
cls
clear all
set more off

input id spellnr  str7 bdate_str  str7 edate_str  employed
       1    1         2008m1          2008m9          1  
       1    2        2008m12          2009m8          0   
       1    3        2009m11          2010m9          1  
       1    4        2010m10          2011m9          0  
       ///
       2    1         2007m4         2009m12          1
       2    2         2010m4          2011m4          1
       2    3         2011m6          2011m8          0
end

* translate to Stata monthly dates
gen bdate = monthly(bdate_str,"YM")
gen edate = monthly(edate_str,"YM")
drop *_str
format %tm bdate edate

list, sepby(id)
```

Corresponding to:

```
     +---------------------------------------------+
     | id   spellnr   employed     bdate     edate |
     |---------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1         1          1    2008m1    2008m9 |
  2. |  1         2          0   2008m12    2009m8 |
  3. |  1         3          1   2009m11    2010m9 |
  4. |  1         4          0   2010m10    2011m9 |
     |---------------------------------------------|
  5. |  2         1          1    2007m4   2009m12 |
  6. |  2         2          1    2010m4    2011m4 |
  7. |  2         3          0    2011m6    2011m8 |
     +---------------------------------------------+
```

Here a given person (`id`) can have multiple spells (`spellnr`) of two types (`unempl`: 1 for unemployment; 0 for employment). the start-end dates of each spell are definied by `bdate` and `edate`, respectively.

Imagine the data was already cleaned, and is such that **no spells overlap** with each other. 
There might be "missing" periods in between any two spells though. 
This is captured by the dummy dataset above.

**My question:**

For each unemployment spell, I need to compute the number of months spent in *employment* in the last 6 months, 12 months, and 24 months.

Note that, importantly, each `id` can go in and out from employment, and *all* past employment spells should be taken into account (not just the last one).

In my example, this would lead to the following desired output:

```
     +--------------------------------------------------------------+
     | id   spellnr   employed     bdate     edate   m6   m24   m48 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1         1          1    2008m1    2008m9    .     .     . |
  2. |  1         2          0   2008m12    2009m8    4     9     9 |
  3. |  1         3          1   2009m11    2010m9    .     .     . |
  4. |  1         4          0   2010m10    2011m9    6    11    20 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------|
  5. |  2         1          1    2007m4   2009m12    .     .     . |
  6. |  2         2          1    2010m4    2011m4    .     .     . |
  7. |  2         3          0    2011m6    2011m8    5    20    44 |
     +--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**My (working) attempt:**

The following code returns the desired result.

```
* expand each spell to one observation per time unit (here "months"; works also for days)
expand edate-bdate+1
bysort id spellnr: gen spell_date = bdate + _n - 1
format %tm spell_date
list, sepby(id spellnr)

* fill-in empty months (not covered by spells)
xtset id spell_date, monthly 
tsfill

* compute cumulative time spent in employment and lagged values
bysort id (spell_date): gen cum_empl = sum(employed) if employed==1
bysort id (spell_date): replace cum_empl = cum_empl[_n-1] if cum_empl==.
bysort id (spell_date): gen lag_7  = L7.cum_empl  if employed==0  
bysort id (spell_date): gen lag_24 = L25.cum_empl if employed==0
bysort id (spell_date): gen lag_48 = L49.cum_empl if employed==0
qui replace lag_7=0  if lag_7==.  & employed==0  // fix computation for first spell of each "id" (if not enough time to go back with "L.")
qui replace lag_24=0 if lag_24==. & employed==0  
qui replace lag_48=0 if lag_48==. & employed==0  

* compute time spent in employment in the last 6, 24, 48 months, at the beginning of each unemployment spell
bysort id (spell_date): gen m6  = cum_empl - lag_7  if employed==0  
bysort id (spell_date): gen m24 = cum_empl - lag_24 if employed==0
bysort id (spell_date): gen m48 = cum_empl - lag_48 if employed==0
qui drop if (spellnr==.)
qui bysort id spellnr (spell_date): keep if _n == 1
drop spell_date cum_empl lag_*

list
```

This works fine, but becomes quite inefficient when using (several millions of) daily data. Can you suggest any alternative approach that does not involve expanding the dataset?

In words what I do above is:

1. I expand data to have one row per month;
2. I fill-in the "gaps" in between the spells with `-tsfill-`
3. I Compute the running time spent in employment, and use lag operators to get the three quantities of interest.

This is in the vein of what done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42890158/management-of-spell-data-months-spent-in-given-state-in-the-past-24-months), in a past question that I posted. However the working example there was unnecessarily complicated and with some mistakes.

---

**SOLUTIONS PERFORMANCE**

I tried different approaches suggested in the accepted answer below (including using `joinby` as suggested in an earlier version of the answer). In order to create a larger dataset I used:

```
expand 500000
bysort id spellnr: gen new_id = _n
drop id 
rename new_id id
```

which creates a dataset with 500,000 id's (for a total of 3,500,000 spells).
The first solution largely dominates the ones that use `joinby` or `rangejoin` (see also the comments to the accepted answer below).

Comment: The question is really about how to speed up the process. The answer is that you may get better timings with `mata`. But this will require considerable coding effort.

Comment: @PearlySpencer Yes, the question is about alternative approaches to get the same result in a more efficient way. I am not so sure that using `mata` is the only way to go here, although I am opened to potential answers involving the use of it.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "efficient". I can tell you from experience that performance-wise, `mata` is your only alternative if you want to stay within the Stata universe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code might save some running time.

```
bys id (employed): gen tag = _n if !employed
sum tag, meanonly
local maxtag = `r(max)'

foreach i in 6 24 48 {
gen m`i' = .

    forval d = 1/`maxtag' {
    by id: gen x = 1 + min(bdate[`d'],edate) - max(bdate[`d']-`i',bdate) if employed
    egen y = total(x*(x>0)), by(id)
    replace m`i' = y if tag == `d'
    drop x y
    }
}
sort id bdate
```

The same logic, along with *-rangejoin-* (ssc) should also deserve a try. Please kindly provide some feedback after testing with your (large) actual data.

```
preserve
    keep if employed
    replace employed = 0
    tempfile em
    save `em'
restore

foreach i in 6 24 48 {
gen _bd = bdate - `i'
rangejoin edate _bd bdate using `em', by(id employed) p(_)

egen m`i' = total(_edate - max(_bd,_bdate)+1) if !employed, by(id bdate)
bys id bdate: keep if _n==1
drop _*
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it would be interesting to test the performance of your second solution with with a large number of spells. If you want to improve your answer I would also explain in words the approach you propose. I am waiting a little more to see if I get more answers, otherwise I will accept yours. Best, S.

Comment: The code is more efficient in the sense that it is shorter. But whether it will be any faster will depend on your data. My hunch says that there will be no noticeable speed improvements because `joinby` is written in the `ado` language and uses extensive I/O operations such as `preserve` and `merge`. If you test it on your data, i will be curious to know.

Comment: I agree, I will do some tests as soon as I have some time. I think program-wise it's interesting to see alternative approaches (including in `-mata-`) since for others the number of spells might not be an issue in itself, and code-readibility might be the first priority (for instance if they have to share codes with co-authors).

Comment: Pearcy is right. *Joinby* seems not effective in this circumstance. I made a small revision for the first solution, making it avoidable from the limitation of *levelsof*. With that, I do believe it would be the better (shorter and faster) than *joinby* solution.

Comment: The revised first approach looks more promising indeed but only if `r(max)` is not very large. Also, I think you could move `summarize` outside the outer loop so it does not repeat every time.

Comment: *r(max)* disappears after *egen y*, therefore, without a local macro to store it, I have to put the *summary* within the loop. But you are right, I have just added 1 more line of macro to put it outside the loop, making it a little more efficient in time consuming.

Comment: I think this approach is the best so far but the inner loop can still be a major bottleneck. It would be ideal if you could find a way to get rid of it. In any case, it would be interesting to see the results if @StefanoLombardi decides to time the different approaches on his dataset.

Comment: I have just updated the solution 2, utilizing *-rangejoin-* instead of *-joinby-*. It is expected that solution 2 now faster than before. Still wondering which one is the most efficient.

Comment: No real difference IMHO. What i said about `joinby` in my earlier comment is also the case for `rangejoin`. Plus you also have to manually install the latter.

Comment: For a larger dataset, e.g, around 1 millions observations, the difference would appear. It is my exoectation.

Comment: By using a 500,000 id's dataset with the same structure of the dummy data in the original question (hence with a total of 3,500,000 spells), I get the following results: first solution: 59 seconds; past solution using joinby: 376 seconds; solution using rangejoin: 562 seconds. Best, S.